# Comparing pointers of object with no data member

Tags: c++, comparator

I have the following Subject-Observor design

```
template<typename Data>
struct Observor{
  Observor()
  {
  }

  virtual void process(Data data) = 0;
};

template <typename Data>
class Subject
{
  public:

   void addObservor(Observor<Data>* observor)
    {
      _observors.insert(observor);
    }

    void removeObservor(Observor<Data>* observor)
    {
      boost::unordered_set<Observor<Data> * > ::iterator itr =
        _observors.find(observor);

      if(itr != _observors.end() )
      {
        _observors.erase(observor);
      }
    }
    protected:

    boost::unordered_set<Observor<Data>* > _observors;
};
```

In the code above, Observor class is inherited by all classes that wish to register to Subject. In the function removeObservor, I get a compile error when I try to create an iterator. The solution suggested to me is to implement a comparator (i.e. <). Observor class however has no data members. What do I base my comparator on?

The solution that came to my mind is to use the typeid of each observor derived class(i.e Derived1, Derived2). This solution however works only if there exists only one object of each derived class is in the set. Since I may have multiple instances of the same object type, I'm stuck on how to proceed

Comment: Huh? You're comparing pointers. For that, you don't have to implement anything. Post unaltered error message.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that the error is that `iterator` is a dependent typename.
Add `typename` to the front of the iterator variable delcaration, or even better use `auto`.

eg,

```
typename boost::unordered_set<Observor<Data> * > ::iterator itr =
    _observors.find(observor);
```

or

```
auto itr = _observors.find(observor);
```